# MarkLogic collections create redundant RDF triples

Tags: marklogic

I have a set of XML documents managed with MarkLogic 9.06. Each document contains (unmanaged) sem:triple elements declaring an "rdf:type" triple and an "rdfs:label" triple:

```
<sem:triple xmlns:sem="http://marklogic.com/semantics">
  <sem:subject>abc</sem:subject>
  <sem:predicate>http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type
  </sem:predicate>
  <sem:object>http://purl.org/dc/terms/BibliographicResource
  </sem:object>
</sem:triple>
<sem:triple xmlns:sem="http://marklogic.com/semantics">
  <sem:subject>abc</sem:subject>
  <sem:predicate>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label
  </sem:predicate>
  <sem:object datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">abc
  </sem:object>
</sem:triple>
```

I notice that for each and every (MarkLogic) Collection a document containing such triples belongs to, the corresponding Named Graph contains an (automatically generated) set of triples, so that if a document belongs to "collection_1" and "collection_2", executing XQuery such as:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" 
  at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

sem:graph(sem:iri("collection_1"))

=>
@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix xs: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<abc> a dcterms:BibliographicResource ,
dcterms:BibliographicResource ;
<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "abc"^^xs:string ,
"abc"^^xs:string .
```

The redundant statements seem harmless (?) in terms of answering Named Graph queries, but is this normal MarkLogic behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear how you are storing your triples exactly, so let me just explain both cases..

With managed triples (those inserted with SPARQL Update or sem:rdf-insert), they will be stored in so-called `<sem:triples>` docs with one and only one collection matching the graph iri. If you insert the same triple in multiple graphs, each will end up in a different sem:triples document with a collection matching each of the graph iris.

With unmanaged, or what I call embedded triples, the situation is slightly different. The document in which the triples are embedded could be in any number of collections. Document collection names can be used as graph iris as well, so if some document has a single triple, but is itself in multiple collections, then that triple will show up as part of multiple graphs in SPARQL.

So, yes, this is expected behavior, and personally I wouldn't consider this harmful. Storage would be clean to my opinion, and the triple will just participate in multiple graphs in SPARQL. I would call that convenient rather than redundant..

HTH!

Comment: Many thanks, that does help clarify what's happening.